# How to move a standalone chart back to an existing sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I regret [moving my chart to a new spreadsheet](https://www.shorttutorials.com/google-docs-spreadsheet/move-chart-to-own-sheet.html) in Google Sheets.

How do I move it back?

Using the revision history to undo the edit is not an option, since it has been a while since the original move, and I would have to undo all the changes since then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can copy the chart and paste it into the sheet you want; then delete the chart sheet. The copy button is in the toolbar:

[image: copy]

Copying preserves the changes made to the chart.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist anymore today...  :-(

Comment: @johey it's there for me. Where are you not seeing the option?